# How to make editable list item using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I want to display user information in a listview with data pulled from a DB. Now my target is to make the listview editable so that when a user clicks on any listview, it responds like a "Textbox" and a keyboard appears (for mobile). After editing, the user can press a "save" button to save his/her editable contents to the DB. 
I am using HTML, jQuery, and CSS with the Adobe PhoneGap API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a fiddle and i think this is what you want :

http://jsbin.com/ijexak/2/edit

In fiddle click over the text to edit and on focusOut of the input element your text will save and input element will hide.

**Updated**

I checked your comment, you should try this:

*Html*

```
   <ul>
       <li>
           <span class="display">erum</span>
           <input type="text" class="edit" style="display:none"/>
       </li>
       <li>
           <span class="display">ingress</span>
           <input type="text" class="edit" style="display:none"/>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

*JS*

```
$(".display").click(function(){
    $(this).hide().siblings(".edit").show().val($(this).text()).focus();
});

$(".edit").focusout(function(){
    $(this).hide().siblings(".display").show().text($(this).val());
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uenZW/2/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes this is working fine but if i try to took more than one <li> tag inside of <ul> and when i click to edit the <li> tag so both of list tags are merged inside one textbox but i dnt want this i want to modify one list tag at a time and textbox should contain only one listitem text. Here is the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/erum/uenZW/                                                              in this fiddle i want when i click on "erum" only that listitem should be replaced by textbox and user will be able to edit it while there would be no chnges in other listitem

Comment: but its not working for dynamic <li> i have posted my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927937/how-to-set-readonly-property-of-dynamic-textbox-using-jquery                                 in this code i have placed dynamic textboxes and filling data from DB but when i need to put <li>dynamically and when user clicked on anyone list item then that list should be hidden and a textbox should appear with value same as the text of <li>

Comment: one more thing when user clicked on list item then a textbox should appear then tell me how to check validation of textbox

Comment: if user erases initial content and leaves blank, then impossible to click & edit afterwards

Answer (score 4):

`<li contenteditable="true"> Editablecontent </li>`

Answer (score 1):

1. attach a click event on your list item.
2. when clicked remove the content of the item and replace it with a form with an input box and button
3. redefine the submit event of the form to perform the desired operation on database
4. remove the form and insert the modified item back in the list.