# How to set readonly property of dynamic textbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to fill a textbox from DB values and I want to set textbox value readonly. When the user clicks on an EDIT option then set all textboxes become editable. I have failed to achieve this. Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#contentid :input').each(function() {
          $(this).attr("disabled",true);
        });

      $('#edit').on('click',function() {
        $('#contentid :input').each(function() {
          $(this).attr('disabled',false);});
        });
     });
   </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="viewInformation" data-theme="d" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text = "back">
    <div data-role="header" id="headerid" class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">
      <h3></h3> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="contentid">
      <a href="#" id="saveDBValue" data-role="button" data-mini="true" style="width:60px; height:40px; float:center;">SAVE</a>
      <a href="#" id="edit" data-role="button">EDIT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
 function getDataofSelectedListItem()
    {
        alert("getDataofSelectedListI");
        clickedListItem = window.localStorage.getItem("clickedValueofList");
        console.log("clicked list item"+clickedListItem);
        //db = window.openDatabase("loginintro", "1.0", "loginintro", 1000000);
        var sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM loginTable WHERE username=\''+window.localStorage.getItem("clickedValueofList").trim()+'\';';

        console.log("selected list query:"+sqlQuery);
        db.transaction(function(tx)
        {
          tx.executeSql(sqlQuery,[],successCBofListItem,errorCBofListItem);
        },errorCB,successCB);
    }
    function successCBofListItem(tx,results)
    {   alert("erer");
      if(results != null && results.rows != null && results.rows.length > 0) 
         {  $('#contentid').append('<label>UserName:</label><input content-editable="false" id="name" type="text"   value="'+results.rows.item(0).username+'"/>');
         $('#contentid').append('<label>EMAIL ID:</label><input type="text" value="'+results.rows.item(0).emailid+'"/>');
         $('#contentid').append('<label>Password:</label><input type="text" value="'+results.rows.item(0).password+'"/>');
    }   
    function errorCBofListItem()
    {
        alert("errorCBofListItem");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JavaScript in the `<head>` is not wrapped in `<script>` tags. Was this a mistake when copying the code onto Stack Overflow?

Comment: yes this was the mistake during copying code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use live for capturing the click event

```
$('#edit').live('click',function()
```

I have created an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UhXe4/)

Example for [dynamic](http://jsfiddle.net/UpNpa/) textboxes

Comment: Why would that be necessary?

Comment: Not necessary. and I looked that .on() method is available from version 1.7

Comment: @GCJavaDeveloper you r talking about static textbox its working for static textbox but no response for dynamic textbox

Comment: This is because the $(document).ready(function() is executed when the page gets loaded so your call to disable the text box will not have any effect on newly created textboxes. you have to add the attribute disabled when you are creating the dynamic textboxes depending on in which mode you are in edit or saved

Comment: @ErumHannan Added an example for dynamic textboxes

Comment: No, this is not necessary since `#edit` exists on DOMReady, so the listener will be bound. All that calls for is for the edit boxes to be available when `#edit` is cliked. [Your dynamic example working without live](http://jsfiddle.net/7n4Px/)

Comment: I was talking about the inputs that are created dynamically after the DOMReady

Comment: Yes. They don't need for #edit to have a live handler either.

Comment: Yes thats correct when you click on edit, but as per his code the dynamically added textboxes will always be editable untill he clicks Save

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850303/how-to-make-editable-list-item-using-jquery

Comment: @GCJavaDeveloper pls can u give me answer of above link i was trying to insert <li> item dynamically at the same place where i put textboxes dynamically but i was failed to edit text of dynamic li item

Comment: thanks @GCJavaDeveloper for giving me your precious time its working fine pls see the above link and also let me know how to apply validations of email , password length on dynamically added textboxes i m using this code for validation how to use that code for dynamically added textboxes  here is my fiddle:                    http://jsfiddle.net/erum/Ztn2a/

Comment: Try using the  [wild card selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). Give an id to you textboxes and append some index to that id and use wild card selector to bind the jQuery method for validation. And you can accept the answer or vote up if this helps you.

Comment: @GCJavaDeveloper how to get text of dynamic textbox here using the code but did nt get text of textbox at submit button:here is my code:   $('#saveDBValue').on('click',function()
    {toggleForm(true);
     console.log("username:" + $('#nameedit').text());
    });   where nameedit is the id of my dynamic textbox

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is something like this:

```
$('input').prop('readonly',true);
```

It has been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306708/add-readonly-to-input-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Your code to disable all input fields is executed at DOMReady, which is before your `successCBofListItem` is executed, i.e. before there are any inputs to disable. You need to make sure it is executed after.

As of jQuery 1.6, use `.prop('disabled', true)` rather than `.attr('disabled', true)`. Furthermore, you need not iterate over the selection and disable each input idividually, you can set the property for the entire collection:

```
$('#contentid :input').prop('disabled', true)
```

If what you've pasted above is your code exactly as it exists in your application, then you need to wrap your javascript in head in `<script>...</script>` tags.

A complete solution might look something like this:

```
function toggleForm(disabled) {
    $('#contentid :input').prop('disabled', disabled);
}

$(function() {
    $('#edit').on('click', function() { toggleForm(false); });
});
```

...

```
function successCBofListItem(tx,results)
{
     if(results != null && results.rows != null && results.rows.length > 0) 
     {
         $('#contentid').append('<label>UserName:</label><input content-editable="false" id="name" type="text"   value="'+results.rows.item(0).username+'"/>');
         $('#contentid').append('<label>EMAIL ID:</label><input type="text" value="'+results.rows.item(0).emailid+'"/>');
         $('#contentid').append('<label>Password:</label><input type="text" value="'+results.rows.item(0).password+'"/>');

         toggleForm(true);
     }
}
```

In your `successCBofListItem` above you also seem to be missing a `}`, which I've corrected above. I've left the `content-editable` attribute in your code above, in case you're using it for something elsewhere in your code, but it is not required for this purpose. `contenteditable` is for editing content that is not a form element.

Comment: @ErumHannan: Sure, I suspected as much. Disregard that part then. The rest of the answer still goes.

Comment: wait trying to implement it anyways but let me knmow where to write this LOC :function toggleForm(disabled) {
    $('#contentid :input').prop('disabled', disabled);
}