# Delete and edit a dynamically created li from ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating `li` by giving input from inputbox and appending the data in `li` by using jquery but after adding the `li` I have added a delete button, but it works, but deleting all `li` by clicking any delete button. How can I delete one by one.
And one more thing how can I edit those `li` by clicking?

This is the code:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var $item = $('#addList').val();

    if($item.trim() == ''){
        alert('please enter the value');
    } else {
        $('ul#listItem').append('<li>'+ $item + '<button class="btn">delect</button>' + '</li>');

        $(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
            $('ul#listItem > li').remove();
            return false;
        });
    }

    $item = $('#addList').val(' ');
});
```

This is the html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="addList">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul#listItem > li .btn', function(){
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this JavaScript to capture all at once:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul#listItem li button.btn', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

When clicking anywhere in your document (complete window), it checks wether the target matches the selector `ul#listItem li button.btn`, which are the buttons in your list. It then looks for the closest `li`, which is the one around the button, and removes it, including the button itself.

Your whole code becomes as following

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var $item = $('#addList').val();

    if($item.trim() == '') {
        alert('please enter the value');
    } else {
        $('ul#listItem').append('<li>'+ $item + '<button class="btn">delect</button>' + '</li>');

    }
    $item = $('#addList').val(' ');
});

$(document).on('click', 'ul#listItem li button.btn', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you :-)
just one thing how can i edit this li ?

Comment: @codeworm That would involve a lot more script. Have you tried anything thus far?

Comment: I have tried this code this working but it edit all thing with in li

' $(document).on('click', 'ul#listItem li button.edit', function() {
          $(this).closest('li').prop('contenteditable', true);
      });'

Comment: I think [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850303/how-to-make-editable-list-item-using-jquery) will point you in the right direction. Takes a little bit more to setup (because of the extra input you have to put in the `li`, but it is a great way to do this right!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
     $('ul#listItem > li').remove();
     return false;
});
```

To:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    $(this).parent("li").remove();
    return false;
});
```

Should work :)